# Testing multiple Spring webApplicationContext in same test

Tags: spring, testing, spring-test

I have 1 application that was a single module with `/intranet/**` and `/internet/**` endpoints. Now I am splitting the application in two modules: `intranet` and `internet`. Each module will create a `war` so now I have **two applications**.

My problem is that I have multiple `junit` tests that invoke `/intranet/**` and `/internet/**` endpoints.
I can't figure how to configure the testing context in a way that I can invoke both application contexts.

In the `intranet` module I have the following configurations:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(...)
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MvcConfigIntra extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  ...
)
```

```
public class IntraWebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    @Override
    public final void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(RootConfigIntra.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webAppContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        webAppContext.setParent(rootContext);
        webAppContext.register(MvcConfigIntra.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcherWebApp = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcherIntranet", new DispatcherServlet(webAppContext));
        dispatcherWebApp.addMapping("/*");

    }

}
```

In the `internet` module it is the same thing:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(...)
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MvcConfigInter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  ...
)
```

```
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public final void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(RootConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webAppContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        webAppContext.setParent(rootContext);
        webAppContext.register(MvcConfigInter.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcherWebApp = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcherInternet", new DispatcherServlet(webAppContext));
        dispatcherWebApp.addMapping("/*");

    }
}
```

Now for tests:

```
@Configuration
@Import({
   ...
})
@Profile("test")
public class IntraTestConfig extends MvcConfigIntra {

}
```

```
@Configuration
@Import({
   ...
})
@Profile("test")
public class InterTestConfig extends MvcConfigInter {

}
```

A test inside `intranet` module:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(
        classes = {
                IntraTestConfig.class,
                InterTestConfig.class
        },
        loader = AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class
)
@ActiveProfiles({"test"})
public class TestInternetAndIntranet {


    private MockMvc mockMvcIntranet;
    private MockMvc mockMvcInternet;

    @Before
    public void init() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvcIntranet = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.ctx).build();

/*HOW TO GET the right AppContext ?!*/
        //this.mockMvcInternet = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.ctx).build();

    }



    @Test
    public final void test1() {
        //This works
        mockMvc.perform(post("/intranet/submeter")

        //This DOES NOT work
        mockMvc.perform(post("/internet/submeter")

    }
}
```

The error is:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'internet/500' in servlet with name ''
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1262)
> at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.render(TestDispatcherServlet.java:105)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
> at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
> at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
> at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
> at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155)

One thing I don't know is how to get the `AppContext` for `mockMvcInternet`.
Is this possible? What's missing in this test configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not use two application contexts.
So, I changed the solution.

I made a new module `old-tests` to put all the tests that invoke `/intranet/**` and `/internet/**` endpoints.
In this module I have a Spring Application Context with all endpoints.